# Gracefully cleanup db and backend after Browser Crash

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am developing a HTML5 UI with JQuery and javascript libraries. The backend is a simple SQL Server db. During the users session a few files and DB tables can be created depending on what they are doing. If the user exits in a normal fashion these files and tables are removed as required.

However if the browser freezes or the user shuts it down via task manager then the I have a bunch of orphaned tables/files. Is there any standard method of cleaning up server side when the client crashes/ended unexpectedly?

Comment: So you using SQL to maintain some kind of state?

Comment: its a multi user system and i craetd a 'sandbox' type system where users can play with the UI without affecting the main data tables - to this is dup'd some tables if necessary and then remove them if not needed anymore. I think what il do is clean up at the start of every session as opposed to the end, this way crash or no crash, the  user starts afresh when logging on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant use time as a measurement of classifying invalid files unfortunately - i just dont know how long it should be idle for. Instead i will cleanup at start of every users session

Answer (score 1):

You could store session id in these temporary tables and discard any data related with user session when it's idle for e.g. 30 minutes.

Again, you could store session temporary files in separate folder and simply delete this folder based on the same condition.

Simple script launched periodicaly should do the trick.

Comment: thanks. I cant use time as a measurement of classifying invalid files unfortunately - i just dont know how long it should be idle for. Instead i will cleanup at srt of every users session. thanks